# Can we build flutter mobile chat application using apache kafka as backend?

Tags: flutter, apache-kafka

I'm new to kafka, i can see a lot of resources done using Firebase for backend storage of chats. Can i use kafka for storing messages for flutter app development.

Comment: https://dev.to/subhransu/realtime-chat-app-using-kafka-springboot-reactjs-and-websockets-lc

Comment: yes, it might possible get help from above link, use Flutter instead react on front end

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/kafka

take a look at this Dart package, The above example for the web I gave to get the idea, the difference will be the only frontend

Comment: Hi i wanted to store messages also in database, instead  of just displaying real time mesaages

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/363928/build-a-realtime-chat-app-which-stores-messages-in-a-mysql-database

check this, if it might help

Answer (score 0):

Kafka client library written in Dart. 
This library is a work-in-progress. Currently all the updates are happening in kafka-0.10 branch:

[Dart Kafka](https://github.com/dart-kafka/kafka)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32128298)